# How to make custom close button in wpf?

Tags: wpf, image

I want to create following form but problem is there when I'm setting the margin with negative value then it will not work and hide my cross image. Is this possible to create as it is? or any other way to create this form.

My need:
(in below image black area is transparent)

[image]

But now show my form like below image:-

[image]

Please let me know appropriate way.

Comment: Did you try using the Adorner or the Popup WPF classes? I guess this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Akku but my need only in wpf winform.

Comment: I don't understand. The popup and adorners can draw outside of the window boundaries, if that is what you fear?

Comment: @Akku because my project is almost done only this thing is need to set.

Answer (score 1):

You can't draw outside of your application, without using Adorners or Popups, as Akku says in the comments.

But what you can do is to, instead of making margins negative, make them positive. So that your content (the gradient background), have a margin of 10 or 20 (or whatever number that produces the right amount of spacing.

```
<Window (.....) AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
       <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="15" Width="15"/>
       <Border Margin="15">
            <YOUR_CONTENT>
       </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```